# C# Datagridview index out of range

Tags: c#, datagridview

In c# windows form application, there is a delete button is the form which is supposed to delete the username in front of it. While it runs fine and deletes the user if the user is on the top of the list but if I want to delete any user in between, it says index out of range. Please advise. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var sendergrid = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (sendergrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
         Db.getInstance().deleteUser(dataGridView1[e.RowIndex, 0].Value.ToString());                
    }
    refresh();
}
```

One image is the windows form with the delete button and the other is the exception.

For more information, Please see the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
dataGridView1[e.RowIndex, 0].Value.ToString()
```

The first index should be the column, so change it to this:

```
dataGridView1[0,e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()
```

Or you can use instead:

```
 dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()
```